# Media query only affecting 2 out of 3 elements?

Tags: html, css, joomla

I am working on a legacy site for someone where a media query does not seem to be having an effect on 1 out of 3 classes. The classes affected are .free-ship, .wholesale, .chronicles

The css for these on standard screen sizes is:

```
    /* Shipping section - Home page */
.free-ship, .wholesale, .chronicles {
    text-align:center;
    height:180px;
    width:30%;
}
.chronicles {
    margin-right:10px;
}
.chronicles a, .wholesale a {
    color:#fff; 
}
```

Now I have in place the following css as media queries:

```
/* Media Queries */
/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 568px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    .free-ship, .wholesale, .chronicles  {
        width:100%!important;
    }
}
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    .free-ship, .wholesale, .chronicles {
        height:230px;
    }
}
```

The problem is, the media query does not seem to apply to the .wholesale class and I can't figure out why? Again, this is not my site, I am just trying to help out. The site is here (removed for privacy). The code refers to the black/grey boxes near the middle of the page.

Any suggestions would be most welcome. I've checked the custom.css file with css lint and this hasn't shown any errors so i'm looking for where I should look next?

Thank you in advance.
D

Comment: Include the relevant code in your post please so that we have a [mcve] of the problem

Comment: Thanks for the pointer Michael - the code was a bit messy so I thought it would be ok to post a link to the page as a simpler solution. I will bare this in mind in the future.

Comment: Thanks. Linking to your website doesn't help the SO community, and that's what these posts are for. If you don't include the relevant code, a year from now when someone searches for a similar problem, finds your post, but your website had changed, and the relevant code isn't in your post... this post is unlikely to help them.

Answer (score 1):

On the live site, it looks like the query isn't targeting ".wholesale," but instead it's targeting an older class called ".world-ship".

You may have changed the class name and it didn't get changed in the media query, or else it hasn't been pushed to live.

[Media Query with ".world-ship" class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrENp.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Ok...The issue was a complete oversight on my part, I forgot the site was cached through a CDN, so even though i've updated the css file and cleared the site cache many times, the changes were not taking affect. I've purged the cache on the CDN and its updated.

Clearly a wood for the tree's problem. Thanks for the answers and comments.